# How to join two different ORM query to return them as one JSON object

Tags: python, json, django-models

I have been trying to output get result of both author name and book name is the same json dict, I got the all the books written by an author but I want author name before books too and here is the relevant code:

**Models**

```
class Books(models.Model):
    bid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bdescription = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bname

class Authors(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    aname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    adescription = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.aname+"\n"


class Bookauth(models.Model):
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='bid', blank=True, null=True)
    aid = models.ForeignKey(Authors, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='aid', blank=True, null=True)
```

**Views**

```
def authbook(request):
    l = request.GET.get('bks', '')
    r = Books.objects.filter(bookauth__aid = l).values('bname')
    s = Authors.objects.filter(aid = l).values('aname')
    return JsonResponse({s: list(r)})
```

this code obviously gives an error regarding s not being a string.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you make a `Bookauth` model, and not use a `ForeignKey`, or `ManyToMany` relation?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I used foreignkey in the bookauth model for connecting  book and authors.

Comment: but it is a bit weird here to do that yourself, since this is more or less what a `ManyToMany` relation will do automatically. Furthermore in case the book or author is removed, you will leave "orphaned" `Bookauth`s.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `{s: list(r)}` to evals to since `r` is a queryset. Could you post an example of the expected json content ?

Comment: Also, you're not only making your life more complicated than it needs to by manually handling the m2m relationship (a m2m field would build the same association table and make querying easier), but you also got the foreignkey fields names wrong - a `models.ForeignKey` points to the related _model instance_ - IOW `somebookauth.aid` and `somebookauth.bid` will not be the foreign key values themselves but the related `Author` and `Book` instances, so it should be `Blookauth.author` and `Blookauth.book`.

Comment: Oh and while we're at it: you should probably not allow `null` for charfields or texfields, since you will have two different possible "empty" values ("null" and the empty string). Better to define them as `null=False, blank=True, default=''`.

Comment: I think I am done with Django.